# How to get sorted list of a folder using google drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I tried to use [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list) method. It returns random list of items in a folder. And I need to get list sorted by title or by last modified date.
Now, I send get request like this:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AHHQVSKDfdFSDUk9PVA/children?maxResults=1000
```

Answer (score 2):

**NB The answer below applies to the v2 API and is out of date. There is now a sort feature `orderby`.**

Looking at your URL, I have two comments:-

1. Giving maxResults=1000 isn't a great idea. Firstly, it leads to timeouts of the API which would be avoided with a smaller value. Secondly, it suggests that you are trying to avoid coding for multiple pages of output, which is a risk since Drive doesn't guarantee that it will always return the maxResults count. It might return less, with a nextPageToken.
2. If you really want to retrieve 1000 entries, it's probably a good idea to specify a projection to reduce the size of the http response.